# How to do Access Token Request in Fitbit API Integration - iOS?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, afnetworking-2, fitbit

I did OAuth2 by using OAuth2 - https://github.com/trongdth/OAuth2-for-iOS ,
I successfully logged in and got response

```
{
        "kOAuth_AccessToken" = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NDIzODY2NzEsInNjb3BlcyI6Indsb2Mgd3BybyB3bnV0IHdzbGUgd3NldCB3d2VpIHdociB3YWN0IHdzb2MiLCJzdWIiOiIzRFJQQzYiLCJhdWQiOiIyMjlROVEiLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NDIzODMwNzF9.5vTYvUAuvMflnOw_7cc1nZoighhtUx4RU26-Q7SewzQ";
        "kOAuth_AuthorizeURL" = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize";
        "kOAuth_Callback" = "http://oauth-callback/fitbit";
        "kOAuth_ClientId" = string;
        "kOAuth_ExpiredDate" = "";
        "kOAuth_RefreshToken" = 97ad2a073f40f21974c8d27cdb74523047f39e98cd2adcfd6f6cc3eb92522d53;
        "kOAuth_Scope" = "activity heartrate location nutrition profile settings sleep social weight";
        "kOAuth_Secret" = string;
        "kOAuth_TokenURL" = "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token";
    }
```

Here - how can I get `code` URI parameter value in the callback URI?

According to [Fitbit](https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/) doc's ---

**Access Token Request:-**
When a user authorizes your application in the Authorization Code Grant flow, your application must exchange the authorization code for an access token. The code is only valid for 10 minutes.

***Authorization Header***:-

The *Authorization header* should be set to Basic followed by a space and a Base64 encoded string of your application's client id and secret concatenated with a colon.

I did this by making use of `AFNetworking` lib, Please have a look on code (header)-

```
-(AFHTTPSessionManager *)getSessionManager {
    if (!self.sessionManager){
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
         sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = nil;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:FITBIT_BASE_URL];
        self.sessionManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url sessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
    }

//    [self.sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:Appdelegate.fitbitAuthorizationString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [self.sessionManager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:Appdelegate.fitbitOAuthClientId password:Appdelegate.fitbitOAuthClientSecret];


    self.sessionManager.responseSerializer = [JSONResponseSerializerWithData serializer];

    self.sessionManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    return self.sessionManager;

}
```

and requested token access - code (parameter's) is

```
NSDictionary *tempParamsDict = @{@"client_id":[JsonUtil stringFromKey:@"kOAuth_ClientId" inDictionary:dictResponse], @"grant_type":@"authorization_code", @"redirect_uri":[JsonUtil stringFromKey:@"kOAuth_Callback" inDictionary:dictResponse], @"code":@""};
```

My request is

```
[dP postJsonContentWithUrl:@"oauth2/token" parameters:tempParamsDict completion:^(BOOL success, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
            // NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
            if (success) {
                NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                /*
                 You got 404 response ,The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was requested.

                 Make sure that you have valid url, try to put your link in the browser and see if it is correct, if the url you requested have special headers
                 */
            }
        }];
```

I am getting - Request failed: not found (404) `error`.
What have I missed and How can I proceed further to get token and access Fitbit APIs?

**Update**
That was happening due to access code so I tried to access code, now I am getting this error

```
description of error->_userInfo:
{
    NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token.json";
    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token.json";
    NSLocalizedDescription = cancelled;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520816/how-to-integrate-fitbit-api-in-ios-app-using-swift/39697291#39697291

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `NSURLSession` use `NSURLConnection` to request data from Fitbit APIs.