# How to integrate FitBit Api in IOS app using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rest, oauth-2.0, fitbit

First of all I created an account at https://www.fitbit.com
Then I careated an app at https://dev.fitbit.com
then installed [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift) using cocoa pods and implemented this method in my AppDelegate

```
    func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    if (url.host == "oauth-callback") {
        OAuthSwift.handleOpenURL(url)
    }
    return true
}
```

now i want to get the data (Name, Steps taken etc) of user account I created at https://www.fitbit.com 
how can I do that ? I searched but was not able to find any tutorial on fitbit integration. And where to use this information in my code?
[image]
 So please guide me about next step what should I do to get the data.

Comment: https://omarmetwally.quora.com/Integrating-the-Fitbit-API-in-iOS-apps    Hope it helps

Comment: @7vikram7 i have seen that as well but i still do not get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FitBit work with OAuth 2.0 API which require Client ID and Secret key. You need these client id and secret key to authenticate with OAuth 2.0 API. 
There is a blog post related to FitBit integration in iOS with Swift.
Lets checkout and learn "How to implement fitbit in iOS"
https://appengineer.in/2016/04/30/fitbit-aouth-in-ios-app/

ex:

```
let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    fitbit_clientID,
        consumerSecret: fitbit_consumer_secret,
        authorizeUrl:   "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize",
        accessTokenUrl: "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token",
        responseType:   "token"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you could do it with basic auth as opposed to OAuth? I had a similar problem trying to POST to MailGun for some automated emails I was implementing in an app.

I was able to get this working properly with a large HTTP response. I put the full path into Keys.plist so that I can upload my code to github and broke out some of the arguments into variables so I can have them programmatically set later down the road.

```
// Email the FBO with desired information
// Parse our Keys.plist so we can use our path
var keys: NSDictionary?

if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Keys", ofType: "plist") {
    keys = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}

if let dict = keys {
    // variablize our https path with API key, recipient and message text
    let mailgunAPIPath = dict["mailgunAPIPath"] as? String
    let emailRecipient = "bar@foo.com"
    let emailMessage = "Testing%20email%20sender%20variables"

    // Create a session and fill it with our request
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: mailgunAPIPath! + "from=FBOGo%20Reservation%20%3Cscheduler@<my domain>.com%3E&to=reservations@<my domain>.com&to=\(emailRecipient)&subject=A%20New%20Reservation%21&text=\(emailMessage)")!)

    // POST and report back with any errors and response codes
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }

        if let response = response {
            print("url = \(response.URL!)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

The Mailgun Path is in Keys.plist as a string called mailgunAPIPath with the value:

```
https://API:key-<my key>@api.mailgun.net/v3/<my domain>.com/messages?
```

Hope this helps!